# Online Return Policies

Tags: law, shopping, online, online-shopping, merchants

I purchased merchandise online from a retailer that has a 365-day return policy. I followed the steps to return the merchandise, filled out the forms to do so, and sent the merchandise back to the address specified. I did purchase delivery confirmation from USPS. The merchandise was delivered back to the retailer 10 weeks ago, but I have not been credited.

When I have reached out to the retailer, I have not received a clear answer regarding whether they have my returns but are not crediting me, or if they lost my merchandise, there was something wrong with the forms I filled out, etc.

I filed a complaint with the Better Business Bureau, and am waiting for resolution. But in the event that the retailer does not respond, what are my rights? We're talking about $500+ worth of merchandise!

Comment: Credit card or debit card?

Comment: Is it united states

Comment: The BBB is useless and impotent.  Call the bank that issued the card.

Comment: "BBB" and "USPS" indicates USA.

Comment: You mentioned the retailer did not provide a "clear answer". What exactly did they say?

Comment: US. Credit card (or possibly PayPal, but I think CC). The retailer replied by asking me what items I had returned and whether I wanted a refund or exchange for each. That's when I was like, "Wait, did you receive my return? Because all that info is on the form." They never confirmed or denied that they had it. They just stopped responding to me.

Comment: Just follow the process. It doesn't matter that you put that info on the form - if they ask you if you want a refund or exchange, *just tell them*. Unless you're just looking for drama, being 'clever' doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you paid by credit card, file a dispute with the credit card company. They will credit you the money immediately while they investigate. The burden of proof will then be on the merchant. Keep your documents handy in case you need them: USPS receipt, proof of delivery, copies of all correspondance, etc.

File the credit card chargeback now, because there are time limits.

[The FTC has more information.](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0219-disputing-credit-card-charges)